# Failure to launch Homestead Vagrant Box

Tags: php, laravel, installation, composer-php, homestead

I am in the middle of following [Laravel Tutorial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#daily-usage) which directs me to installing the homestead vagrant box; I am stuck on composer part.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64bit) and ran Vagrant through virtualbox 5.0.24r108355 (amd64). Apparently Homestead has conflict with virtualbox 5.1.

My understanding of Homestead is that it will set up

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Git
PHP 7.0
HHVM
Nginx
MySQL
MariaDB
Sqlite3
Postgres
Composer
Node (With PM2, Bower, Grunt, and Gulp)
Redis
Memcached
Beanstalkd
```

This is partly confirmed by the following: 16.04 LTS installation.

```
yhk@home:~/Homestead$ vagrant ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-22-generic x86_64)
* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Last login: Fri Jul 15 13:20:08 2016 from 10.0.2.2
```

However, when I try `vagrant up`, it fails. Apparently, I am already using composer. How do I proceed along to fix this glitch and have vagrant up and running properly?

```
yhk@home:~/Homestead$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
yhk@home:~/Homestead$ vagrant provision
==> default: Running provisioner: file...
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20160715-14549-1a6hi0t.sh
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: script: Creating Site: homestead.app
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: script: Restarting Nginx
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: script: Creating MySQL Database
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: script: Creating Postgres Database
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: script: Clear Variables
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: You are already using composer version 1.1.3 (stable channel).
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20160715-14549-l87w5y.sh
```

I think the setup properly done...

```
yhk@home:~/Homestead$ ls
CHANGELOG.md   composer.lock  init.bat  LICENSE.txt  scripts  Vagrantfile
composer.json  homestead      init.sh   readme.md    src

yhk@home:~/.homestead$ ls
after.sh  aliases  Homestead.yaml  Homestead.yaml~
```

Once again, how do I proceed along to get composer issue fixed and have vagrant up and running?

Comment: I do not think you have an issue with composer. A provisioner ran and concluded no changes needed to be made to that software. Unless you have an error somewhere.

Comment: The fact that you are able to `vagrant ssh` into the box seems to me like it is in fact up and running. What makes you think it's not, aside from the composer update not running because you are already up to date?

Comment: Ah - perhaps then I am just lost in terms of how things operate in vagrant/homestead. When I used anaconda 3, I could tell the environment I was in from the prompt. I can see that with `vagrant ssh` but nothing with `vagrant up`.

Comment: My follow up question is - what does `~/Homestead` exactly do? Would I have to create all projects within this directory? Can I not create project in (let's say) ~/repository/php/? The reason I am asking is that `vagrant up` doesn't seem to work elsewhere. `composer require laravel/homestead --dev` doesn't work in `~/repository/php`, saying command composer can't be found. 
`composer require laravel/homestead --dev`

Comment: `yhk@home:~/repository/php$ vagrant up` says that 
"A Vagrant environment or target machine is required to run this
command. Run `vagrant init` to create a new Vagrant environment. Or,
get an ID of a target machine from `vagrant global-status` to run
this command on. A final option is to change to a directory with a
Vagrantfile and to try again."


`yhk@home:~/repository/php$ composer require laravel/homestead --dev`
" No command 'composer' found, did you mean:
 Command 'compose' from package 'mime-support' (main)
composer: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to run vagrant up with sudo privileges?
cd to Homestead folder and execute

```
sudo vagrant up
```

and then see if the error remains. sometimes this is a issue related with permissions.

Comment: Running Vagrant with `sudo` will make your permissions problems worse, not better.

Comment: I had a similar case, that the only way vagrant could run on my machine was with sudo.  I am just saying give it a try (lol)....